# getting nullPointerException when trying to call fragment method in my Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

I am trying to do something relatively basic by drawing a circle on a fragments layout when the app user presses down on the screen. essentially drawing a small circle on the area of the screen where a user presses.  So i started with a basic project with a fragment in the main layout.I have a gestures class that extends simpleOnGestureListener. this returns the coordinates for my circle to the main activity. this works fine. but in my onTouchEvent method in the main activity when i call frag.drawCircle() i get a nullpointerexception and I am not too sure why this is. below is the code for my MainActivity. i think I am doind everything correctly including getting the fragment using the fragmentmanager and using its "tag" to retrieve the fragment? below is the code for my main class.

```
public class Circles extends Activity {

private GestureDetector detector;
private PlaceholderFragment frag;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_circles);



    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.activitylayout,  new PlaceholderFragment(),"myfrag")
                .commit();
    }

    detector = new GestureDetector(this, new Gestures());
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    frag = (PlaceholderFragment) manager.findFragmentByTag("myfrag");

}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
  boolean consumed = detector.onTouchEvent(event);

  float x = Gestures.x;
  float y = Gestures.y;

    if(consumed)
    {
        Log.d("consumed? ", String.valueOf(consumed));
        Log.d("x : ", String.valueOf(x));
        Log.d("y : ", String.valueOf(y));
        frag.drawCircle();
    }

   return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.circles, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {



    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_circles, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }


    public void drawCircle()
    {
        Log.d("stuff", "draw circle here!");
    }
}
```

}

obviously the fragments isn't being instantiated properly. I am just not too sure why that is at present. any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post your logcat trace

Comment: If you are initializing the fragment, why not save a reference to it right then and there? The fragment transactions are executed asynchronously. If you are going to use it right away, you need to call `getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();`

Comment: okay. i thought using the fragmentmanager to get the fragment was the correct way of going about retrieving it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `onResume` method and try moving this code in `onResume`

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
frag = (PlaceholderFragment) manager.findFragmentByTag("myfrag");
```

Comment: that doesn't make sense to me if oncreate is called then the fragment should be available? or do i need to get the fragment in a thread and wait() on the main thread?

Comment: It would take some time to be available

Comment: so as onresume is called first the fragment may be available when i call the method on it? but then again it may not? maybe its best i run it in a thread.

Comment: In thread also you will have to put a delay otherwise its no use. Try to do it in `onResume` first

Comment: okay i will try that. is this mentioned in the android documentation? iam going to have to read over it again.

Comment: yeah putting it in onResume worked. still not 100% on why it does but thanks!

Comment: For that please go through the Activity life cycle. Understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution will be doing everything in onCreate(). Doing in onResume will just destroy the meaning of having onCreate and moreover just confuse the control flow if reference of that fragment is required before the execution of onResume.

Instread of putting everything in one statement, just break it and make it fit your need.

Here is the code

```
private PlaceholderFragment frag;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_circles);



if (savedInstanceState == null) {

    frag = new PlaceHolderFragment();

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.activitylayout, frag ,"myfrag")
            .commit();
}else{
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    frag = (PlaceholderFragment) manager.findFragmentByTag("myfrag");

}
detector = new GestureDetector(this, new Gestures());

}
```

This way you wont have issue getting a null reference. Since if activity is recreated the Fragment will be in backstack so you can retrieve it by tag. But if activity is being created forthe first time then first get reference and then commit the transaction.